# Proving onto function with strings

Tags: discrete-mathematics, functions

I am trying to prove that this function is onto:

> Let $S$ be the set of all strings of $0$’s and $1$’s, and define $D: S \to \Bbb{Z}$ as
> follows: For all $s \in S$, $D(s) =$ the number of $1$’s in $s$ minus the
> number of $0$’s in $s$.

I know that it’s onto, I understand more or less why. I know we should have three cases, when $x = 0$, when $x > 1$ and when $x < 1$. But for the last case $(x < 0)$, I don't understand why it's the image of string $0^x$ instead of the image of $0^{-x}$ (because in this case $x$ is negative and $-x$ is positive, so how can we have  a negative number of zeroes)?

Thank you in advance!
[image]

Comment: I believe you are correct that it doesn't make sense. It seems like a mistake to me. For example, clearly $D(0^5) = -5$. In general, if $x$ is negative you are correct that $D(0^{-x}) = x$

Comment: Yes, it's a typo. You can see that they referred to $0^{-x}$ when they said "Let us consider ...", but the forgot the "$-$" after that.

Comment: @masiewpao Thank you for answering! So for the proof would the correct way of writing this be D(0^x) = 0 - (+x) = -x?

Comment: No, not if $x$ is negative, as the expression $0^x$ would be meaningless. The correct way is simply to note as you already have that $D(0^{-x}) = x$, where here x is negative. that alone proves the negative $x$ is mapped to from some string in $S$.

Comment: It probably happened because "$0^{-x}$" just looks weird. While it is a valid proof, I'd have 1) used $n$ instead of $x$ - people expect $x$ to possibly be any real number, not just an integer, and 2) I'd have written the "second second" case as "third case", kept $n \gt 0$, and said $D(0^n) = -n$. It's valid, but not well written.

Comment: @masiewpao Thank you!

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Thank you! That makes more sense to me

Comment: Not a problem good luck!

Comment: Yes, good luck. And it's a great sign that you're really understanding what's going on when you look at the argument, think "that's not right", but can say "oh, they probably meant this, which is right".

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed at least a typo in the given proof. The result is actually easy to prove. Indeed, for all $a, b \geqslant 0$, one has by definition
$D(1^a0^b) = a-b$. It now suffices to prove that for any integer $c \in \Bbb{Z}$, there exist two nonnegative integers $a$ and $b$ such that $c = a - b$, which should not be too difficult to establish...